# Visual Studio setup project: bundle prerequisites into one installer

Tags: windows-installer, setup-project, prerequisites

When creating a Visual Studio setup project, is it possible to bundle the MSI file and setup.exe into one executable? I know the setup.exe checks for prerequisites and then runs the MSI file afterwards. The main goal is to simplify the installation process so the user only has to download and run one executable.

Any idea on how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some developers use a zip-type program for this. Basically you add the setup.exe, prerequisites and MSI into a self-extracting exe that will run setup.exe after it unpackes everything. I think IExpress will do this, as well as 3rd party tools like WinZip.

Other setup authoring tools have their own bootstrappers which can include all the installation files.